# PHP error- Header sleep function not working

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` code that has `header` and `sleep` **Functions** to display an alert as it redirects the page a bit slower. But the `sleep` does not seem to be working.

This is the `PHP` code, Please check:

```
<?php

   if ($query) { 
         echo '<script language="javascript">';
         echo 'alert("Registration SUCCESFUL")';
         echo '</script>';
         header('sleep(10);');
         header('Location: http://localhost/amberTAG%20requester/Login%20Page/Login.html');
 } else {
         echo '<script language="javascript">';
         echo 'alert("Registration UNSUCCESFUL, Sorry!")';
         echo '</script>';
    header('sleep(10);');
}
 ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `sleep` without `header`

```
sleep(10);
header('Location: http://localhost/amberTAG%20requester/Login%20Page/Login.html');
```

Or use:

```
header('refresh:10; URL=http://localhost/amberTAG%20requester/Login%20Page/Login.html');
```

Comment: Same there too.. add `echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Registration UNSUCCESFUL, Sorry!")';
echo '</script>';
sleep(5);`

Comment: Didn't understand.

Comment: Try using this: `header('refresh:10; URL=http://localhost/amberTAG%20requester/Login%20Page/Login.html');` without sleep before

Comment: Thanks alot @Thamilan

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sleep before alert, you should use `setTimeout` for `JavaScript`.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Registration UNSUCCESFUL, Sorry!");
}, 10000);
```

And, if you want to use sleep before URL redirection, try this:

```
header( "refresh:10;url=yoururl.html" );
```

Comment: how will i write this in php

Comment: OK, now I understand what you need. @Thamilan's answer is right.